# Working on Eclipse 3.8 with Rails 4.0: Project/App Explorer does not show new files, maybe because of git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, git, ide

Been working on Hartl's Rails tutorial. However, after starting chapter 6, I found that Eclipse's App Explorer does not show any new files anymore.
Eg running `rails generate model User` does indeed generate the file `user.rb` in `app/models/`, however the App Explorer does not show the file.
Also, when I just copy and paste other files like images, css etc. into the app's folders they are not shown in eclipse.

Maybe I screwed up with git? Thanks for your help!